# Translation of 衣冠禽兽 to English

Tags: formal-language

How to say a man who in human clothe but acts just like a total beast, means this man is an animal, hated people.

In Chinese words: 衣冠禽兽, which Google tranlates to *crowned beast*, but I don't know how to say it in English.

Comment: Re. Edit history. Maybe because the word "fucking" is so often used in movies today, and (maybe) in some video games too, it's easy for non-native speakers to think it is part of everyday language. But for some, the expletive is still a highly offensive and vulgar term, which is probably why your question attracted 3 downvotes. Lastly, the offensive term was also totally unnecessary, it added nothing of value to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the OP might find the following idiom useful

> a **wolf** (the beast) **in sheep's** (kind gentle animals) **clothing**

It means a malicious person who pretends to be kind and polite.

*Wikipedia* says

> ### [wolf in sheep's clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_in_sheep%27s_clothing)
>
> The phrase originates in a sermon by Jesus recorded in the Christian New Testament: *Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing*, but inwardly they are ravening wolves (Gospel of Matthew 7:15, King James Version). The sermon then suggests that ***their true nature will be revealed by their actions*** (by their fruits shall ye know them, verse 16).

Comment: Great answer. As an extreme example, [this newspaper article](https://www.journaltribune.com/articles/stateregional/wolf-in-sheeps-clothing-bar-harbor-man-who-raped-and-killed-former-classmate-gets-58-years/) uses that exact term to describe a violent criminal. (Warning: link contains graphic content.)

Comment: This is a bit too literary. This is not what I originally wanted, but it is still a good idiom, but I usually don't use it. I think it's easy to be misunderstood and doesn't express the emotions and feelings I want.

Comment: @Traveler-0013 the origins are literary but as J.R.'s link shows it is still very contemporary.

Comment: @Traveler-0013 did you say what the Chinese idiom mean? Did you explain the emotions and feelings you want to express? If my answer is not what you were looking for, and I suggested it might not be in my opening statement, then you have a great opportunity to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A1%A3%E5%86%A0%E7%A6%BD%E7%8D%B8)

> beast in human attire; gentleman in appearance but a beast in conduct; immoral or despicable person

There isn't a single word translation.